# How to get a docker image to run an executable

Tags: docker, wget

I want to run a .exe in a docker container. Below are links to the source.

Git:  https://github.com/jcreynolds/NodeLink
Hub:  https://hub.docker.com/r/jcreynolds/nodelink/

The docker container appears to build however it will not run.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit#1:  This is for use in unraid

Edit#2: added the unraid docker log

```
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV php: /usr/local/emhttp/plugins/dynamix.docker.manager/scripts/docker 'start' 'NodeLink'
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: device veth8fb01c8 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: docker0: port 10(veth8fb01c8) entered forwarding state
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: docker0: port 10(veth8fb01c8) entered forwarding state
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV avahi-daemon[2619]: Withdrawing workstation service for veth958915c.
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: docker0: port 10(veth8fb01c8) entered disabled state
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: eth0: renamed from veth958915c
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: docker0: port 10(veth8fb01c8) entered forwarding state
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: docker0: port 10(veth8fb01c8) entered forwarding state
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: veth958915c: renamed from eth0
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: docker0: port 10(veth8fb01c8) entered disabled state
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: docker0: port 10(veth8fb01c8) entered disabled state
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV avahi-daemon[2619]: Withdrawing workstation service for veth958915c.
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV avahi-daemon[2619]: Withdrawing workstation service for veth8fb01c8.
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: device veth8fb01c8 left promiscuous mode
Jul 14 12:50:41 BennySRV kernel: docker0: port 10(veth8fb01c8) entered disabled state
```

Edit#3: solved! the issue was in the docker run command 
(the difference is the the -i) does anyone know what -i does?

the run command that works:

```
docker run --name=NodeLink --net="bridge" -i -e TZ="America/Chicago" -v "/mnt/user/Config/NodeLink":"/config":rw -p 8090:8090/tcp -d jcreynolds/nodelink
```

the run command that it was trying to use:

```
docker run -d --name="NodeLink" --net="bridge" -e TZ="America/Chicago" -p 8090:8090/tcp -v "/mnt/user/Config/NodeLink":"/config":rw jcreynolds/nodelink
```

Edit: added the code in question:

The docker file code:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#...

# Adding Custom files
##################
COPY startup.sh /tmp/startup.sh
RUN chmod -v +x /tmp/startup.sh && sleep 1 && /tmp/startup.sh && rm /tmp/startup.sh
CMD ["/NodeLink/NodeLink.exe"]
```

The startup.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e "/NodeLink/NodeLink.exe" ]; then
cd /NodeLink
wget http://automationshack.com/Files/NodeLink.exe
fi
mono /NodeLink/NodeLink.exe &
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings emitted when you try to the container?  Anything that would help provide clues as to why it wouldn't run as expected?

Comment: A docker file uses a CMD or an ENTRYPOINT to specify what service to run. Why do you additionally RUN a startup.sh before? Also is your exe a service or is it something that executes something and then terminates?

Comment: @TechSpinX the additional RUN was my last ditch effort to make this go.  I am novice when it comes to creating docker applications.  The .exe is a service that runs a web gui, by default its on port 8090.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just run a Windows executable in a Docker container.  I have no opinion on running it under mono, but if your startup.sh script actually works, it should probably be the entrypoint to your container.

```
RUN chmod -v +x /tmp/startup.sh
ENTRYPOINT /tmp/startup.sh
```

For some explanation- running the command in the Dockerfile starts a process that ends immediately when that RUN command is done.  There are no background processes running when a Docker container starts- just the parent process that is the ENTRYPOINT.  You are trying to feed a windows executable to Bash, which will not work.  Instead, start a shell, launch your background process, and have that shell launch bash- the bash shell then is the parent process, and it will keep your background process running until you exit the shell.

Comment: I built the docker image and container manually first per these instructions:  http://forum.universal-devices.com/topic/19214-nodelink-docker/  .  It appeared to work fine.

Comment: So what were you trying to accomplish when you modified that Dockerfile?  Because you're unfamiliar the ENTRYPOINT I mentioned would work the same (in this case) as the CMD from that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Windows executable in a Docker container, the same way you do it under Linux, using wine or Mono.

See https://hub.docker.com/r/solarkennedy/wine-x11-novnc-docker/

as a good example.

If your Windows executable needs dotnet20 or dotnet45, you will need to do `winetricks dotnet20` or such in your Dockerfile